# azure function poppler utils

Tags: python, azure

I want to create an Azure function app using python.
In my app, I need to convert a pdf to image.
This needs to use popple-utils.
When I run the app and I want to convert the pdf to image: `convert_from_bytes(file_name,500)` I got this error: `Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?`
how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to dockerize the Azure function and it worked completely
Just need to add ad Docker file in root of the project like this:

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.7
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \ 
AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true 
COPY requirements.txt / 
RUN apt-get update -y 
RUN apt-get install poppler-utils  -y 
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt 
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

Then dockerized it and pushed it to Azure Registry.

- navigate to your Azure portal
- create an Azure function (docker)
- navigate to deployment center
- address your docker image
- and it will work ok