# How can I install poppler in azure web app?

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service, poppler

I'm using windows 11 and I used following command to install poppler in windows which worked great for me.

`conda install -c conda-forge poppler`

Now, when I try to deploy my flask app in Azure web app which is having **linux** machine. It's giving me following error.

`Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?`

I know this error but I don't know how to resolve it in **ubuntu 18.04 machine**.
After looking through a lot of stackoverflow and askubuntu questions. I'm still unable to find my answer.

**Note 1:** Links I have gone through but none of them worked for me:
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522374/how-to-install-poppler-for-python-3-in-linux)
[Link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112856/how-to-install-poppler-0-73-on-ubuntu-18-04)
[Link3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781552/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-poppler)

**Note 2:** I'm using Azure devops. I checked my CI-CD pipeline without **pdf2image** and it's working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service runs your Web app in a sandbox and installing 3rd party tools is not allowed.  The solution is to deploy your app in a container and run it in App Service Web App.  You can configure your Azure DevOps pipeline to build your container, push it to a container registry like Docker Hub or Azure Container Registry and set your Wb App to retrieve and run the container.

Comment: Ok. So, there is no other way around?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use a custom startup file for the azure app service and add that startup file to your configuration on the app service blade.

**Step 1)** Your startup.txt file should look as below. Please update the gunicorn settings on the third line if you are using a different naming convention for your flask app

```
apt-get update
apt install poppler-utils -y
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 600 app:app
```

**Step 2)** Add **startup.txt** to your project root directory

**Step 3)** Now update your app service configuration on azure as below. You should also remember that this does not install the latest version of poppler but it will help to run pdf2images

[image]

Comment: May be this could help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69737044/4723876